# Save Image after UICollectionView closes in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, uicollectionview, popover

I have UICollectionView that has a button that opens the camera and save that image to UICollectionView

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo{
[self.images addObject:image];
//NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[self.images count]]);
NSIndexPath *ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.images count] inSection:0];
[picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.galleryView reloadData];
IDMPhoto *photo;

photo = [IDMPhoto photoWithImage:image];
photo.caption = @"Sample";
[photos addObject:photo];
```

}

Now my problem is I have a Done button, How can I save the images to gallery and add a (filename+number). and by the way UICollectionView is embedded in PopOver

and lastly, Is it possible that when ever I open the UICollectionView it will retrieve the images in gallery.

I hope you can Help me.....THANKS! :D

Answer (score 0):

If your Done button is also embedded in the popover (I assume so), just use delegation and create a protocol in your popover `ViewController` interface file.  Let the presenting `ViewController` be a delegate to that protocol and then fire off that delegate method when you finish picking the image.

Something like this:

```
@protocol MyCollectionImagePickerDelegate
    -(void)doneSelectingImage:(UIImage *)image;
@end

@interface MyCollectionViewPopoverController : UIViewController {
    __unsafe_unretained id <MyCollectionImagePickerDelegate> _delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyCollectionImagePickerDelegate> delegate;
```

And then in the:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo { 
    [_delegate doneSelectingImage:image];
}
```

In your presenting VC class you would just implement that method and do what you need to with an underlying collection (`NSArray` I assume).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion I'll try it first :) I'll let you know if it works